# How to find forks of a repository in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, fork

In GitLab I am able to see who has forked my repository by clicking the following link:

[image: GitLab fork list example]

Does anyone know if there is a similar capability within Azure DevOps?

I was able to find the following API call however it doesn't seem to work:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/forks/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

-> I pass it a repo and various container ids where I know there are forks of that repo and it returns empty results.

Even when I find a fork in Azure devops by manually traversing the UI I cannot find a place to view where that repo was forked from.

Any help on the above would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you notice thats its preview 6.1 of the api?

Comment: Yes I did notice that - this behaviour applies to all versions of the API.

Answer (score 2):

If you create a pull request for a repository that has been forked, its "into" options will include a select box that includes the list of forks from that repository.

[image: pull request example]

Comment: This is unorthodox, but works and none of the API calls I tried worked, so yeah, totally strange way to list forks but it does it :)

Answer (score 1):

> Even when I find a fork in Azure devops by manually traversing the UI I cannot find a place to view where that repo was forked from.

You could use the REST API [Forks - Get Fork Sync Requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/forks/get-fork-sync-requests?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to retrieve all requested fork sync operations on this repository:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryNameOrId}/forkSyncRequests?api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

As the test result:

[image]

We could to know the repo ID where current repo was forked from.

And we could use the [Repositories - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/repositories/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to know the name of the Repo:

[image]

**Update:**

> In GitLab I am able to see **who has forked my repository** by
> clicking the link. Does anyone know if there is a similar capability
> within Azure DevOps?

If you want to know who forks your repo, you could just use your REST API

[Forks - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/forks/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0):

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryNameOrId}/forks/{collectionId}?api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

And we could use the oraganiztion id for the `collectionId`. We could use following RETS API to get the oraganiztion id:

Post [https://dev.azure.com/{organization1}/_apis/Contribution/HierarchyQuery?api-version=5.0-preview.1](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization1%7D/_apis/Contribution/HierarchyQuery?api-version=5.0-preview.1)

Body:

```
{
    "contributionIds": ["ms.vss-features.my-organizations-data-provider"],
    "dataProviderContext":
        {
            "properties":{}
        }
}
```

The test result:

[image]

Comment: "Forks - Get Fork Sync Requests" returns zero results for me, even though I know forks of the repo exist. I think this potentially only returns results if people configure synchronization to take place vs a one time fork.

Comment: @platinum_pidgeon, Ok, if I understand you correct, you want to get who fork your repository？But you said in your question,  ”I cannot find a place to view where that repo was forked from.“， above method could only return the parents forks based on the child forks. So, you want to know the child forks based on the parents forks？

Comment: @platinum_pidgeon, If I understand you correct, please check my updated answer.